# Cannot boot after a failed update from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 Update

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, 15.10

I was running Ubuntu 15.04 on my HP EliteBook 755 and was updating to 15.10 when the update process was stuck for several hours at the same place, so I hit the power button to reboot.

Now the system won't boot: After going through many attempts at fixing this issue, I have tried a boot-repair but it continues to ask for specifying a repository for grub2.

Here is the [boot repair info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14882284/).

I have a lot of work on those disks that I don't want to lose, so I am hesitating to do a new install of Ubuntu 15.10 unless I have absolutely no chance of fixing and rebooting with my current system.

*I would greatly appreciate any expert help on this issue.*

Answer (score 0):

You've got the lot: Logical volumes, overlapping partitions, unknown file systems, ...

So: the best thing you can do right now is to **stop using your hard disk!**

Then boot from an Ubuntu 15.10 Live DVD and: (increasing numbers means increasing difficulty and less of your data will be recovered)

1. Restore your latest full system back-up.
2. If you don't have a full system back-up, install 15.10 and do a file restore from your data backup (You did mention you had important files, so you must have a data back-up, right?)
3. Make a duplicate onto another (bigger) hard drive and do the recovery on the copy!  If you mess up the copy, just make another one!

   1. Run [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) first to recover your photo's onto your back-up drive (yeah: you need a back-up drive too!) so that you can skip them in the next step; [manual here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).
   2. Run [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) to recover any other data; [manual here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).
4. [Read how to efficiently back up a single PC here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc).

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. I basically went with reinstalling 15.10 after able to back my important data on the hard drive. I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: Don't thank me @veasna. Just click the acceptance icon. That's all the thanks i need...